# Is there a system of multiple interacting quantum particles for which the density can be obtained analytically?

Tags: density-functional-theory, reference-request, ab-initio-calculations, model-hamiltonians, many-body-physics

I know that it is impossible for real electrons and nuclei. In the Kohn and Sham approach, a system of interacting electrons is approximated by a system of non-interacting Kohn-Sham particles in an effective potential.

My question refers not to a real chemical system. Rather, I am asking about a system of toy particles that don't necessarily correspond to reality.

Is there such a system of multiple interacting quantum particles for which density can be obtained analytically for arbitrary number of particles, at least in terms of some special functions, say, hypergeometric functions?

The particles may be point particles, they may interact not necessarily at contact, may be only pairwise interactions, maybe in 1D, etc.

Comment: You mean like "2 interacting photons", rather than the particles you mentioned so far (electrons and protons)?

Comment: How about the Hubbard chain?

Comment: @NikeDattani Is it [this one](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/2040-8978/18/10/104005) ? I just googled "2 interacting photons" and reading. I didn't want to specify them to be necessarily photons or particles of matter. Just artificial point particles moving in space, like in toy problems in quantum mechanics courses. I am curious if anyone found a system that by chance happens to be analytically solvable for any n interacting particles?

Comment: @Anyon Thanks for suggestion. I need to read more about it. I edited my question and added: 'I want these particles to move in space, and the interaction depend on spacial coordinates.' I am not sure, if particles in Hubbard chain can do that but I know too little about it.

Comment: Let's see if we get any answer at all, before making it even more restrictive to particles whose interaction depends on space (any answer to the former will probably satisfy the latter restriction anyway).

Comment: What about Hooke's atom? It's a 3D system of 2 fully-interacting electrons, which is exactly solvable.

Comment: @PhilHasnip Thanks! I didn't know about it. I wonder, can it be generalized to arbitrary number of electrons? Maybe by modifying its potential?

Comment: I don't think so, and it's only soluble analytically for certain "magic" values of the interaction strength, but it's still a nice playground for multi-electron physics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anyon suggested the Hubbard chain:

> "How about the Hubbard chain?"

and Phil Hasnip suggested Hooke's atom:

> "What about Hooke's atom? It's a 3D system of 2 fully-interacting electrons, which is exactly solvable."

for certain "magic" values of the interaction strength:

> "I don't think so, and it's only soluble analytically for certain "magic" values of the interaction strength, but it's still a nice playground for multi-electron physics"